# Xpath wrong using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 
            
            
URL = 'https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/yukon-gold-casino-casino'
driver.get(URL) 



data=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//section[@class='review-text richtext']")
        
for row in data:
    try:
        para0= row.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[text()[contains(.,'Games')]]/following-sibling::p[following::h2[text()[contains(.,'Support')]]]").text
    except:
        pass  
    
    print(para0)
```

I want they collect the data of `Games` only but they also get the data of `Virtual Games` so how we restrict the `contains method`  that get only data of `Games` only kindly recommend any solution for that these is page link https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/yukon-gold-casino-casino

Want these only

[image]

do not get these text of `virtual game`
[image]

Comment: I do not see any ´Virtual Games` text in the link you shared, honestly. I mean, the second screenshot I do not see it

Comment: they are in different link check these https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/spin-casino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[contains(.,'Games')]` will match both `Games` and `Virtual Games`.
What you can do here is:

1. Use `equals` instead of `contains`, like this:

```py
"[text()='Games']"
```

2. or use `starts-with`:

```py
"[starts-with(text(), 'Games')]"
```

So this line `para0= row.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[text()[contains(.,'Games')]]/following-sibling::p[following::h2[text()[contains(.,'Support')]]]").text` can be changed to

```py
para0= row.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[text()='Games']/following-sibling::p[following::h2[contains(.,'Support')]]").text
```

or

```py
para0= row.find_element(By.XPATH,"//h2[starts-with(text(), 'Games')]/following-sibling::p[following::h2[contains(.,'Support')]]").text
```

Comment: try these `//p[starts-with(text(),'Games')]/following-sibling::p[following::h2[text()[contains(.,'Support')]]]`  not working

Comment: In the question you mentioned `h2` but here `p`...

Comment: Also I tried to fix your XPath more, see the updated answer

Comment: Great, @Prophet, as always, I did not know the `following` as attribute. I leave here another xpath that can help in case they change the Support `h2` to any other `h2` word. Xpath: `//p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][text()='Games']]`

Comment: Thanks @JakyRuby, I didn't explain here about `following-sibling`, just used it as is. But yes, there is such operator in XPath. As about your alternative XPath expression unfortunately I can't check it since my company is blocking casino web sites...